# Adding Pointer results in error to class error overloaded member function not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having some problems with my code. specifically:

```
bool Customer::checkout(Inventory* inv) {
  double total = 0;
  for( unsigned int i=0; i < _Cart.size(); i++ ) {
      total += _Cart[i].price; // price * quantity??
  }
  if( Customer.balance < total ) {
      return false;
  }
  else {
      unsigned int i =0;
    for ( i =0; i < inv->_Inv.size(); i++) {//go through inventory, check names, if there is a match, 
          if (inv->_Inv[i].name == _Cart[i].name) {     //decrement the quantity accordingly, if there is no match, 
              inv->_Inv[i].quant -= _Cart[i].quant;
              break;
        }
    }
    if( i == inv->_Inv.size() ) {  //you need to push the new food into the inventory vector
        inv->_Inv.push_back(_Cart[i]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

And in my header file I have:

```
class Customer {
  public:
    Customer( string n, int c, double b );
    bool addCart( Food f );
    bool removeCart( Food f );
    void report(); //to do
    bool checkout(Inventory* inv); //to do
  protected:
    string name;
    int card;
    double balance;
    //CreditCard _CC;
    vector<Food> _Cart;
};

class Inventory {
  public: 
    vector<Food> _Inv;
    vector<Food> _Purchases;
    int interval;
    void firststock( string fileName );
    void showFirststock( string fileName);
    void restock( string file, int inter );
    void summary(); //to do
```

The errors I get are the following:

1. error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Inventory' error C2061: (Regarding bool checkout(Inventory* inv);)
2. syntax error : identifier 'Inventory' bool
3. Customer::checkout(Inventory *)' : overloaded member function not
   found in 'Customer' see declaration of 'Customer' .... (Regarding bool Customer::checkout(Inventory* inv))

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You need a forward declaration to `Inventory` before the definition of `Customer`.

```
class Inventory;
class Customer {
    //....
};

class Inventory {
    //....
};
```

Some notes on the code:

- pass complex datatypes by `const` reference - for example - `bool addCart( const Food& f );` instead of `bool addCart( Food f );`
- Your use of unqualified `string` suggests you have `using namespace std;` somewhere in the header. That's not OK, you should, at least in headers, not have `using` directives, but rather fully qualify the type - `std::string`, which should also be passed by reference

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I still haven't tried the above out as i haven't had time, but can you clarify on passing std::string as a reference as well? or give me an example with the code i have provided? I mean obviously there is code i have not provided so if i haven't provide the right context or code that is okay then. Thanks for the help though i appreciate it. If you need me to add a little more maybe I can.

Comment: @AjMunot I've already posted the suggestions & the solution, for the rest you can use google and research for yourself. If something isn't clear, you can come back and ask away.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If i have anymore problems i will be sure to ask